# How to center a bullet in itemize using LaTeX?

Tags: vertical-alignment, itemize

I'm trying to create a list of bullets containing some math in LaTeX, but the default settings of LaTeX put the bullets in the beginning of the first line , due to the use of equation the result is very messy....
Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $g^{(k)}(\psi)=\frac{(n^{2}-1)\delta}{(n-(k-1))((1-\psi)k-(n-1)\delta)}$
\item $f^{(k)}=(g^{(k)}\frac{1}{n})$
\item $\underbar{k}=\frac{n(1+\delta)}{2}$.
\item \begin{equation*}
\underbar{f}=\begin{cases}
n\delta&\mbox{If }n<4\mbox{ or }n=4\&\delta>\frac{1}{8}\\
f^{\underbar{k}}&\mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\item \begin{equation*}
\underbar{g}=\begin{cases}
n\delta&\mbox{If }n<4\mbox{ or }n=4\&\delta>\frac{1}{8}\\
g^{\underbar{k}}&\mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I need to move the last two bullets vertically to the middle:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you really want to use an `itemize` list for such formula? I suggest an `align` environment` for all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to move the two final bullet points to the right, I'd drop the use of the `equation*` environments and move the math material to the left, so that all bullet points have the same alignment. (Better still, don't use an itemize environment at all. Look into, say, using an `align*` environment, with all equations aligned on the respective `=` symbols.)

I can't help but comment on the use of the `\underbar` instruction: It typesets its argument in an upright font, and it doesn't adjust the position of the bar if the argument is a letter that has a descender component (such as the letter "g"). Can you maybe find a better notation (or at least a more suitable macro, say, `\underline`)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $g^{(k)}(\psi)=\dfrac{(n^{2}-1)\delta}{(n-(k-1))((1-\psi)k-(n-1)\delta)}$
\item $f^{(k)}=(g^{(k)}\frac{1}{n})$
\item $\underbar{k}=\dfrac{n(1+\delta)}{2}$
\item $ \underbar{f}=\begin{cases}
n\delta&\text{If $n<4$ or $n=4$ \& $\delta>\frac{1}{8}$}\\
f^{\underbar{k}}&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
\item 
$\underbar{g}=\begin{cases}
n\delta&\text{If $n<4$ or $n=4$ \& $\delta>\frac{1}{8}$}\\
g^{\underbar{k}}&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead \underbar is (as you  mentioned) \undeline. Two thing will change: underline is on right place and variable apear in italic (math variable) shape, what is to me more correct.